# run astyle on all files before git-commit

Tags: git

I use `astyle` to get my Java and C++ into a unified look. Sometimes I write something and check it into git before running `astyle`. So I will end up with a commit message like `Run astyle` which makes cherry-picking and all the like more difficult.

I tried to write a pre-commit hook, but that cannot alter what is going to be commited, it will just fix it in the next commit. I tried a filter, but that does not change the files on the disk.

Is there some neat way to get git to run something before even assessing the changed, other than writing a small script (and remember to use it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like if you use both the filter (to fix the committed files) and the pre-commit hook (to fix the files on disk), it will do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is rather old, I'm missing one answer:

you can `git add [options]` within the pre-commit hook, as such the solution is quite simple:
just add each file changed by what ever formatter you're using and continue with the commit.

Comment: Ellipses tell us your thought it incomplete and leads me to distrust your answer. Please edit your answer to clarify it and make it more specific and concrete.